# Can't replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, system-installation, windows

I have Windows 7 and wanted to replace it with Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin), but when I was booting and starting installation of Ubuntu I chose to replace Windows on my SSD, and it saw this problem:

> "/dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating  that it has a GPT table. However,it does not have a valid fake MS-DOS partition table, as it should. Perhaps it was corrupted-possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT partition tables. Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an msdos partition table. Is this a GPT partition table?"

Even when I click yes or no, it does not move on it seem like a no responding situation. 
Do I need [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to solve it?

Comment: [Solved](http://askubuntu.com/questions/486556/no-partitions-found-while-installing-dual-boot-win8-ubuntu-14-04) I used the method and it worded. hope it works for you 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to re-make the partition table, a quick fix.  Boot off the LiveCD and select "try Ubuntu".  Next run Gparted and select Device -> create partition table.

You can select advanced options which will give a menu where you can select GPT (GUID partition table) if want, and if the drive is larger than 2TB then I would recommend that you do so.

After you have have written a new partition table, you can select "install" and everything should go smoothly.